# three.js Clicked mesh surface texture color

Tags: three.js

I have sphere mesh with colored texture.

```
var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {                             

               blending   : THREE.NormalBlending,
               transparent: true,
               map   : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.jpg" ),
               opacity    : 0.3,

                                            } );


       sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( (100), 32, 32 ), Material );
       scene.add( sphere );
```

Get the clicked point:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
     raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
     var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cameradestinations, true );


    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {                         
          var mypoint = intersects[0].point   
                                 }
```

How to get the current texture color in the clicked point `mypoint`?

Comment: As the three.js scene is on a canvas, maybe all you have to do is read the color from the canvas. Just a thought.

Comment: Seems the simple way to get the color at a position with 2d context, does not work with webgl context. So it's not as simple as I thought.

Comment: Yes i left that way, i approach to parts out of my knowlodge, im finding simple way